# About Rendro Countdown

Tags: jquery

I want to make countdown plugin with rendro countdown from https://github.com/rendro/countdown, and this my code:

```
function dhiscomingsoon_enqueue(){
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery.countdown.min',$plugin_url.'assets/js/jquery.countdown.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.countdown.min');
}

function dhiscomingsoon_footer(){
    global $options; $options = get_option('dh_iscomingsoon'); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var endDate = "<?php echo $options['dhiscs_countdown']; ?>:00";

            jQuery('.countdown').countdown({
                date: endDate,
                render: function(data) {
                    jQuery(this.el).html("<div>"
                                         + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 3)
                                         + " <span>days</span></div><div>"
                                         + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2)
                                         + " <span>hrs</span></div><div>"
                                         + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2)
                                         + " <span>min</span></div><div>"
                                         + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2)
                                         + " <span>sec</span></div>");
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function dh_iscomingsoon_init(){
    // do stuff
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dhiscomingsoon_enqueue');
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'dh_iscomingsoon_init' );
```

But not work on frontend, if want work i must insert

```
wp_register_script('jquery','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Can you tell me how to make this work without:

```
wp_register_script('jquery','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Thankyou...

Comment: The jQuery that ships with WordPress is already in noConflict mode. What error messages do you see in your browser's error console?

Comment: No error message, but countdown not work.